# f is uniformly continuous if for all $x$ and $y ∈ \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |x−y|^\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let f : R → R be a given function. The following property will ensure that f is uniformly continuous:

for all $x$ and $y ∈ \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |x−y|^\frac{1}{2}$.

**My attempt :**
From definition a function $f$ is uniformly continuous if for a arbitrary $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that for any two points $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
$$ |x-y| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon
$$

Now let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. Then
$$ 
 |x−y|^\frac{1}{2} \lt \epsilon \\ 
\implies
 |x-y| \lt {\epsilon}^2 = \delta \\ 
\implies |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon
.$$

Therefore the function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: The implications are in the wrong direction.

Comment: Now is it correct?

Comment: Yes, basically if $|x-y| < \epsilon^2$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \delta$ is enough, and part of what you wrote. Read up "$\alpha$-Holder continuity", which is the condition that $f$ satisfies for $\alpha = \frac 12$.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon okay. BTW can you give me any article or reference or pdf about Absolute continuity? I can't find anything that'll make me understand what it is and how visually it's comprehended and properties of it etc etc.

Comment: @Pritam "visually it's comprehended" is a bit of an issue, because absolute continuity is not a "local" property, so you cannot look in the neighbourhood of a point for intuition. They behave weirdly : absolutely continuous functions are a.e. differentiable, and the FTC extends to these functions. These results are covered in the relevant chapters of Rudin and H.L.Royden, and basically every property of a.c. functions arise from their a.e. differentiability. I do not know of texts that cover just a.c. functions in detail, however.

Comment: Also, the definition of an absolutely continuous function goes hand in hand with the generalized notion of *absolute continuity* of a measure over another measure. The Radon-Nikodym theorem and similar results show that absolute continuity is constructed to be a minimum requirement to pull off results of that kind, which are ever so important in PDE etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely are on the right track. Given $\epsilon > 0$ you have to find a $\delta > 0$ such that the implication $|x-y| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon$ holds.

So the correct order of arguments would be: Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. Set $\delta = \epsilon^2$. Then $\delta > 0$ and
$$
 |x−y| \lt \delta  \implies |f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |x−y|^{1/2} < \delta^{1/2} = \epsilon \, .
$$

Comment: But in the edit I've gone in the right implications just as you did here.

Comment: @Pritam: Yes. But you should start with defining a suitable $\delta$ and then assume that $|x-y| \lt \delta$ ...

Comment: Okay thanks Martin : )

Comment: BTW can you give me any article or reference or pdf about Absolute continuity? I can't find anything that'll make me understand what it is and how visually it's comprehended and properties of it etc etc.

Comment: @Pritam; Sorry, but I have not.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but the logic isn't quite there.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Now you need to show there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $| x - y| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y) | < \epsilon$.

As you say, a good choice is $\delta = \epsilon^2 > 0$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
&\quad\quad\quad|x - y| < \delta
\\&\implies | x- y| < \epsilon^2
\\&\implies |x-y|^{\frac{1}{2}} < \epsilon
\\&\implies |f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x-y|^{\frac{1}{2}} < \epsilon
\\&\implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon
\end{align}
$$
This shows that there exists a $\delta > 0$ (namely $\epsilon^2$) such that if $|x - y| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

From definition a function $f$ is uniformly continuous if for a arbitrary $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that for any two points $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
$$ |x-y| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon
$$

Now let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. Then let $$\delta = {\epsilon}^2.$$ Then
$$ |x-y| \lt {\epsilon}^2 = \delta \\ 
\implies |x−y|^\frac{1}{2} \lt \epsilon \\ 
\implies |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon
.$$

Therefore the function is uniformly continuous.